# genymotion inside virtual system without opengl, is it possible?

Tags: android, opengl, emulation, smartphone, genymotion

See post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033916/how-do-i-fix-ralloc-c-for-mesa-opengl-driver-compilation

Virtual pc info: a hyper-v virtual remote desktop pc with windows 64 bit, 7gigs of RAM, 8 cores, and a video card which does NOT support OpenGL.

Neither Genymotion nor Bluestacks nor genymotion plugin for Eclipse works inside the virtual pc, and the android studio virtual phone does work if I set it to android L preview but is agitatingly slow and shows no buttons, making it impossible to navigate. Any smartphone type would do, I just want to be able to test specific applications in a phone-like environment.

I tried compiling custom mesa libraries for opengl support in both 32 and 64 bit, can not change any video card settings or update any drivers on the virtual PC.

Q1:If you have a virtual pc with a virtual video card which does not support openGL, how would I get genymotion to emulate a phone within the virtual OS?

Q2:What alternatives do people know of which would not require OpenGL support, besides android studio phone emulator?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I'm going to disappoint you!
I have this exact same question and as far as I've found, it's most likely impossible due to lack of providing GPU hardware acceleration support in hyper-v guests.
but the thing is if you run hyper-v from Windows Server 2008 R2 or win Server 2012 you can get access to your GPU resources with an extra tool called "RemoteFX vGPU", you can find out more about it here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx

so i guess we're stuck with this crappy AVD Manager emulator until Microsoft man up and provide a descent solution for all of hyper-v revisions, sorry again for the bad news! i myself am still in shock!