# Error of connection with my account on Genymotion

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I installed GenyMotion + VirtualBox in a Virtual Machine. The installation is succeed but when I tried to connect with my account from GenyMotion application, I had this error : 
Le numéro d'identification de l'application GenyMotion est invalide

Any Help please !!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to my question is here :
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide
And us a solution :
[genymotion inside virtual system without opengl, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075860/genymotion-inside-virtual-system-without-opengl-is-it-possible)